# PHP images link to HTML

Tags: php, html, image

I can't seem to find out why my PHP wont link up with my HTML. The idea is to have certain pictures pop up based on a survey. For example, if the numbers add up to over 50, "bromley.jpg" will pop up. That doesn't happen though it just says "dorm" instead of the picture.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title> Find the right dorm for you </title>

        <h1>Find out what dorm fits your lifestyle!</h1>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Please fill out a few quesitons so we can help you figure out which dorm      is best for you. </p>

    <form method="get" action="slutsky1-results.php">

        I enjoy (check all that apply):<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="act1" value="8">Working Out<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="act2" value="3">Bowling<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="act3" value="3">Live Music<br>     
        <input type="checkbox" name="act4" value="5">Shopping<br>   
        <input type="checkbox" name="act5" value="7">Food<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="act6" value="9">Bars <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="act7" value="9">Frat Parties <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="act8" value="8">Sports <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="act9" value="3">Library <br>


        Is being close to the quad important to you?:
        <select name= "Quad">
        <option value="1">Not important</option>
        <option value="3">Kind of important</option>
        <option value="6">Very Important</option>
        <option value="3">Only thing that matters</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        How often do you plan on going to Red Lion?:
        <select name= "Lion">
        <option value="1">Never</option>
        <option value="5">Sometimes</option>
        <option value="10">Over 3 times a week</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        Would you rather go to the ARC or CRCE?:
        <select name= "Gym">
        <option value="10">Arc</option>
        <option value="1">CRCE</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        How do you plan on eating most of your meals?:
        <select name= "Gym">
        <option value="5">Ordering delivery</option>
        <option value="8">Walking To Green St.</option>
        <option value="5">Making my own food</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        Private or Public dorm?:
        <select name= "Gym">
        <option value="10">Private</option>
        <option value="5">Public</option>
        </select>
        <br>



        <input type="submit" value="get my results!">

    </form>



    </body>
</html>
```

slutsky1-results.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Dorm results! </title>
        </head>

        <body>
        <h1> Your ideal dorm based on your answers is...</h1>
        <p>
        <?php


        // Generates answer based on total numbers accumuated throughout survey.
        $dorm= dorm ;
        echo "Our reccomendation is $dorm <br>";
        ?>



     <img src="<?php

        if ($value > 50 ){
        echo "bromley" ;
        }
        else if ($value>15 && $value <31) {
        echo "Allen" ;
        }
        else if ($value>30 && $value <50) {
        echo "peabody" ;
        }
        else if ($value>0 && $value <16) {
        echo "PAR FAR" ;
        }

         ?>.jpg">


        </p>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this all one document you load into a browser?  If so this setup is completely (100%) broken.

Comment: `$dorm= dorm ;` is not PHP-compliant. A string has to be enclosed in `"` or `'`. Or is this supposed to be a variable (`$dorm`)?

Comment: You are never setting the variable $value.  Therefore your code will pass over all the if/else if statements and never create a valid src for the image.

Comment: No these are two separate documents sorry I just wanted to show both of them...It's supposed to be a variable (I think a variable is the best way to do what I'm trying to do). Basically I have a survey, each answer gets a certain amount of points. By the end of the survey whatever number the survey gets will bring up a certain picture. Is a variable not the way to go about this???

Comment: Steve, what am I doing wrong regarding the $value? I want to have the values in the survey add up and link to the php, should $dorm actually be $value?

Answer (score 1):

You basic problem is that you expect value to be the sum of all your values in the select dropdowns.  Form submissions don't work that way.  You need to get the value of each selected option separately and then add them up.  Something like this:

```
$value = 0;
$value += $_GET["Quad"];
$value += $_GET["Lion"];
$value += $_GET["Gym"];
$value += $_GET["Meal"];
$value += $_GET["Private"];
```

This would go before the image tag and would take the selected value of the "Quad" select and add it to the total.  then it would take the value of the "Lion" select and at it, etc.

This is not pretty, but it should get you in the right direction and give you an understanding of how forms are submitted.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are not filling $value with the actual value.

Put the following before $dorm=dorm :

$value = $_GET["value"]

Assuming you are calling your results script  like results.php?value=50

Comment: I get so lost with variables...So basically I have the values from the survey. I call these "value" and then should I set $value=$_GET["value"] so the browser gets that info. Then how do I get that to translate into finding the right picture?

Comment: Once you have set that variable, the rest of the script will work fine, and the right picture will show up.

Comment: He can't set a GET variable, for 2 reasons: 1) He doesn't know what value to transmit, because it is dependent on the values selected. 2) he is using a POST (because of the form submit).  The problem is that he needs to calculate the value on the second page.

Comment: 1) that's correct. He has to calculate the value before submitting. 2)Form method is GET. Please, doublecheck.

Comment: I put the $value=$_GET ["value"] in and now nothing shows after i submit the survey, before it would say "according to our results we recommend you live in dorm and dorm should have been a picture of the correct dorm. Does the PHP have to be named results.php? and whats the part about ?value=50

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm very new to this-it's actually my first course on programming. Am I doing something too complicated here? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @Sircom You are correct, I overlooked the fact that he is using GET.  That doesn't change the fact that he can't submit a value.  The purpose of this exercise is to submit the selections and THEN calculate the outcome.